# I am using bootstrap 3, I designed a website which is working perfect in 1366*768 resolution but not looking good in larger devices.?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

[This is how i want in all other larger devices. i.e. above 1366*768 resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B1a6.png)

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

You can set max width to main container/body

like 
      body{
          max-width:1366px;
          margin : auto;
         }

Whenever you set max-width 1366px site is zoom upto 1366px and after than it remains no change with in width and margin auto maintain your site content in the middle/center. 
[image]